# Change style of element on hover of it's child with just CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have a site with a changing background image, on hover of certain elements. The image is usually dark, but sometimes light. The light images have the class `.whiteImg` applied to them.

I have gotten this to work with just CSS, by having the 'background' images set as the sibling of the element that is hovered. For example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link 3</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" class="whiteImg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
li a:hover + img{
opacity: 1;
}
```

Now that all works fine. But I have `body{color: #fff;}` by default but that needs to change to `#000` when `.whiteImg` is visible. I've tried solving this with jQuery (and it's color plugin) but the animation happens after the CSS animation. So I'm looking for a pure CSS solution to *make the `body` `color` change to black at the same time as `.whiteImg` is shown.

Is there anyway to do this? I'm looking for something similar to

```
 li a:hover + img.whiteImg < body {
    color: #000;
 }
```

which is inspired by the end of [this post](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) but obviously doesn't actually work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to change the whole page's color? Or just the hovered link? If the latter then simply `li a:hover {color: #000}` is enough. Edit: also, why not use normal background-images instead of absolutely positioned `img` elements? Also 2, why not put the images inside the links?

Comment: `<` Is this some new selector which I am the only who seems to have missed? ps. it's invalid

Comment: There's not yet a parent selector in CSS3. You have to use Javascript for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: @Mr. Alien: It's not. It's just a hypothetical selector dreamed up by the author of that article (i.e. "wouldn't it be nice if we had a parent selector like this?"). Fortunately OP knows it's hypothetical and knows it's invalid, but it's very commonly mistaken to be a real selector.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes I know that, we also had a question few weeks back which said why don't we use `<` to select a parent...

Comment: In my opinion the best parent selector would be `body:target .children { }` where the element with `:target` pseudo-class would be the target of the CSS rules applied.

Comment: @Fez Vrasta: `:target` is already used to mean something else: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo The proper term for what you're suggesting is "subject", and a subject selector has already been proposed, albeit in the form of a symbol and not a pseudo-class. See Selectors 4: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: `:target` was just an example :)

Comment: Your images are formatted so that they span the whole viewport already – so wrap them in a span, make that span as big as the viewport as well, and give that span the background color – since those spans come after your links, you _can_ select them when the links are hovered.

Comment: But it's the text on the rest of the page that I'm trying to affect.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer add jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only pure CSS solution I can think:

http://jsfiddle.net/7K83g/3/

```
li, li * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.whiteImg ~ .fakebg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

This is a 100% solution, uses `direction: rtl` to apply the right position to the links.

With jQuery instead:

```
 $(document.body).toggleClass("dark");
```

CSS:

```
 .dark { background: black; color: white; }
```

Will do the trick.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QKAh6/

Comment: I'm not trying to affect the background on hover, that's already done. I'm trying to affect the color of the text.

Comment: watch the edit. And by the way I've said it was just a concept, the trick works, you have to use it in the right way, but the trick itself works.

Comment: I know but I'm trying to affect the color of all of the text on the body, because the fake background of the entire page is changing

Comment: just make two classes "light" and "dark" to apply to the body element and switch them with jQuery, watch this site, has the exact effect you are trying to archieve: http://subtlepatterns.com/

Comment: As said, I've tried using jquery already but it clashes with the css transition for timing.

Comment: As said, subtlepatterns does it, so it's possible, and if you don't give us your complete CSS we can't understand where is the problem with **your code**.

Comment: That does look really nice, however it just misses out the CSS in my question which sets the images as a kind of fake background (with opacity transition). I've forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8mwD3/) but those transitions/hover effects don't work. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: CSS transitions can't be used to fade a background-image, but with a `<img>` tag as you did should work, just check the code and fix the errors.

Comment: I'm confused... What is the error? Something to do with the `a:hover` not working on an `li`?

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. I didn't notice you'd put the imgs into the li, makes  sense.

Answer (score 0):

As [the post your refer to](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) suggests, the `>` selector is a wish, not an actual implementation. Reality is you can't select a parent in CSS.

It also states an alternative jQuery method:

```
$('p:has(img)');
```

In your case, this would be:

```
$('body:has(img.whiteImg)').css('color', '#fff');
```

Just run this when you are triggering the image change.

---

Alternatively, to make it easier, you can just add or remove a class to the body when you are starting to fade in the new image.

```
body {
    color: #000;
    transition: color 0.4s;
}

body.negative { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: As said in my question, I've tried jquery but that clashes with the css transition animation for the background.